# Sniffing packets over a wifi network, with or without monitor mode using wireshark

Tags: wireshark

So, I am actually confused, there are some guides that say you can't just capture traffic on wireless LAN with promiscuous mode and you need to setup monitor mode, also enter the wifi password to be able to decrypt the data.

But then there are some guides that say as long as the device is on your lan network, you can capture their wifi traffic fine with promiscuous mode over a wireless network.

So which one is it actually?

Answer (score 1):

If you are capturing (sniffing) traffic on a LAN with one subnet, you do not need promiscuous mode or monitor mode to do this. Standard network will allow the sniffing.

Below is a packet sniffing sample between two different machines on the same network using Comm View.  Wireshark works roughly the same way.

The source machine is on wireless for this exercise.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can capture packets on a WiFi interface either in managed mode or if your hardware supports it, monitor mode too.  If you're not interested in IEEE 802.11 management/control frames or radiotap headers, and you only care about traffic to/from your capture device, then you don't need to use monitor mode.  What you'll get instead are packets that have fake IEEE 802.3 framing instead.

However, if you do care about management/control frames or radiotap information or capturing all traffic on a particular channel, then you will either need to set your interface card to monitor mode or use an external device capable of capturing IEEE 802.11 traffic.  Note that not all WiFi cards support monitor mode and support may vary depending on your operating system.

For more information about WiFi capturing, I'll refer you to the Wireshark wiki page, [WLAN (IEEE 802.11) capture setup](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN).  Note that the Wireshark wiki is being migrated to GitLab on August 11, 2020, so this link may become broken or possibly you'll be redirected automatically, I'm not sure.